# Browsersync to browse files

Tags: browser-sync

I am using browsersync to work on some apps.
Is it possible to deliver/show files if no index.html is available?

```
browser-sync start -s -f .  --port 9000
```

Currently I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it: `--directory`

```
browser-sync start -s -f .  --port 9000 --directory
```